# Encoding issues with Disqus API results (2 Unicode characters which should be interpreted as one)

Tags: qt, encoding, character-encoding, disqus, qstring

I have got a Qt application which receive strings in JSON objects from the Disqus API:

```
{ "title": "Swiftkey pr\u0102\u0160dit votre choix d\u2019emoji gr\u0102\u02d8ce au clavier Swiftmoji" }
```

(there's more but I only write what matters here)

Then I put the `title` string in a `QString`:

```
// Assuming that "reply" is the QNetworkReply * containing the Disqus API response.
QByteArray disqusReply = reply->readAll();
// disqusReply == "{ \"title\": \"Swiftkey pr\u0102\u0160dit votre choix d\u2019emoji\ gr\u0102\u02d8ce au clavier Swiftmoji" }"
QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(disqusReply);
QJsonObject obj = doc.object();
QString title = obj["title"].toString();
```

Later I write it in a QML Text. It should display "*Swiftkey prédit votre choix d'emoji grâce au clavier Swiftmoji*" but it displays "*Swiftkey prĂŠdit votre choix d'emoji grĂ˘ce au clavier Swiftmoji*" instead.

As you can see there are some encoding issues, with two successive Unicode characters which should be interpreted as one character only ("*ĂŠ*" instead of "*é*" and "*Ă˘*" instead of "*à*" here). How can I do (with Qt or QML) to display the right characters? Which encoding conversions I have to perform (with Qt or QML) in order to solve those encoding issues?

Additional informations: the bug occurs on Windows 10 64-bit.

EDIT : you can find the bug here: https://disqus.com/api/3.0/threads/list.json?since=2016-05-18T14%3A08%3A27%2B00%3A00&forum=frandroid&api_key=7o0xSBOEzN2AG6yxcJgeJbeEbACBfGhgnoIRHu7umbifKAvXQpisYKT3KSXF9nPN

Comment: Based on your sample code it's hard to say if this has anything to do with the Disqus API, since you're using a string literal. In the case of your sample code, you should be wrapping that string literal in a [QStringLiteral](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#QStringLiteral)

Comment: @MrEricSir I receive the string right from the Disqus API. Here I use a string literal just for the example. Consequently I cannot use that `QStringLiteral` macro. Have a look at my edit.

I do not know if it has something to do with the Disqus API. What I want is to display the response just like it should be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think the problem in double encoding or something else from server side, not from client's. Because your code must be `pr\u00e9dit` instead of `pr\u0102\u0160dit`. If you'll use `clean_title` instead of `title` of your json-answer you'll get the right string cause it's encode is correct.

**UPD:**

As I said in comment - there are two replies with same news. Id **4836688567** has wrong encode string. And **4836587900** correct. There are many double variants of news with different encoding.

**First:**

```
{
"feed":"https://frandroid.disqus.com/httpwwwfrandroidcomandroidapplications358721_swiftkey_predire_choix_demoji_grace_clavier_swiftmoji/latest.rss",
"identifiers":[],
"dislikes":0,
"likes":0,
"message":"",
"id":"4836688567",
"createdAt":"2016-05-18T09:08:43",
"category":"448171",
"author":"3938134",
"userScore":0,
"isSpam":false,
"signedLink":"http://disq.us/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.frandroid.com%2Fandroid%2Fapplications%2F358721_swiftkey-predire-choix-demoji-grace-clavier-swiftmoji&key=nqCbe6jgfwM-skLyqTf3lg",
"isDeleted":false,
"raw_message":"",
"isClosed":false,
"link":"http://www.frandroid.com/android/applications/358721_swiftkey-predire-choix-demoji-grace-clavier-swiftmoji",
"slug":"httpwwwfrandroidcomandroidapplications358721_swiftkey_predire_choix_demoji_grace_clavier_swiftmoji",
"forum":"frandroid",
"clean_title":"Swiftkey pr\u0102\u0160dit votre choix d\u2019emoji gr\u0102\u02d8ce au clavier Swiftmoji",
"posts":0,
"userSubscription":false,
"title":"Swiftkey pr\u0102\u0160dit votre choix d\u2019emoji gr\u0102\u02d8ce au clavier Swiftmoji",
"highlightedPost":null
}
```

**Second:**

```
{
"feed":"https://frandroid.disqus.com/swiftkey_predit_votre_choix_d8217emoji_grace_au_clavier_swiftmoji/latest.rss",
"identifiers":["358721 http://www.frandroid.com/?p=358721"],
"dislikes":0,
"likes":1,
"message":"",
"id":"4836587900",
"createdAt":"2016-05-18T08:16:30",
"category":"448171",
"author":"3938134",
"userScore":0,
"isSpam":false,
"signedLink":"http://disq.us/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.frandroid.com%2Fandroid%2Fapplications%2Fgoogle-apps%2F358721_swiftkey-predire-choix-demoji-grace-clavier-swiftmoji&key=UU8IrLN_UDXEggF6wHjAYg",
"isDeleted":false,
"raw_message":"",
"isClosed":false,
"link":"http://www.frandroid.com/android/applications/google-apps/358721_swiftkey-predire-choix-demoji-grace-clavier-swiftmoji",
"slug":"swiftkey_predit_votre_choix_d8217emoji_grace_au_clavier_swiftmoji",
"forum":"frandroid",
"clean_title":"Swiftkey pr\u00e9dit votre choix d\u2019emoji gr\u00e2ce au clavier Swiftmoji",
"posts":13,
"userSubscription":false,
"title":"Swiftkey pr\u00e9dit votre choix d&#8217;emoji gr\u00e2ce au clavier Swiftmoji",
"highlightedPost":null
}
```

As you see, difference in url from where news comes. But why some of them encoded wrong - this is a question.

**UPD 2:**

Or maybe it's **RSS** bug. Let's take `prédit` word. In second variant RSS returns xml with content which has been already encoded to é and feed link looks like normal. In first variant RSS returns ĂŠ and its feed link looks like anormal - feel like it takes whole url and do another encode.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had a look at Disqus replies and unfortunately both `title` and `clean_title` fields have the same string.

Comment: @air-dex, oh, my mistake. There are two replies with same news. Id `4836688567` has wrong encode string. And `4836587900` correct. And the interesting thing - there are everywhere double variants of news with different encoding. And the second always right.

Comment: **UPD1:** I saw those double variants.

Comment: **UPD2:** What I'd like to know is this "*another encode*", the one which transforms "*é*" in "*ĂŠ*". Once this is known the problem is almost solved.

Comment: @air-dex, experiments said that it's another utf8 encode.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```cpp
QByteArray disqusReply
    = QString::fromUtf8(reply->readAll().data()).toLocal8Bit();
```

? You might prefer delaying this conversion until actually writing the string into the QML text.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this and it changes nothing.

Answer (score 0):

QJsonDocument requires UTF-8 encoded strings. Is your document encoded in UTF-8 when you load it?

Comment: I did it testing @aconcagua's respionse below: `QByteArray disqusReply = QString::fromUtf8(reply->readAll().data()).toLocal8Bit();`.

Comment: The point is that if your data is not UTF-8 encoded, it won't help. Can you paste your sample data somewhere?